# Correct way to write this increment

Tags: php

What is the right way to write this increment.

```
$up = 0;
echo "<button type='button' name='buy".$up++."' >Buy</button>";
```

and this line as well

```
if(isset($_POST['buy'.$up++])){
```

I know both of these are wrong. So what is the right way to write these.

Comment: if you want use arrays, just use arrays (`name='buy[0]'` => `$_POST['buy'][0]`)

Comment: You  might want to look into either a `for` or `while` loop, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to solve a problem that has already a solution with HTML form arrays,

```
echo "<button type='button' name='buy[]' >Buy</button>";
echo "<button type='button' name='buy[]' >Buy</button>";
echo "<button type='button' name='buy[]' >Buy</button>";        
print_r($_POST['buy']));
```

However, it is more commonly used with checkboxes:

```
<input name='id[]' type='checkbox'\>
<input name='id[]' type='checkbox'\>
<input name='id[]' type='checkbox'\>
$id = implode(',',$_POST['id']);
echo $id
```

Since only one button could be clicked at any given time, wouldn't you prefer them to have unique ids instead of an array ?

```
echo "<button type='button' name='buy".$productId."' >Buy</button>";
```